# UITableViewCell design to indicate expansion, what kind of indicator?

Tags: uitableview, ios7, user-experience

I have a table of review items, each one can be of variable length. I need to show a snippet of the review content in each cell and allow the user to tap on it to expand the review content in place. A disclosure rectangle seems wrong since it is usually associated with a navigation behavior, i.e. the screen slides in from the side. I want to expand in place.

What do people usually use for this? The review list in question is only part of a design for an iPad app (right side of two columns) so my choices are (1) popover (2) expand cell in place or (3) replace the entire column with the full review content.

I would rather expand in place but the disclosure arrow seems wrong to me, what type of common indicator would make more sense?

Implementation is not an issue, not sure what UX choice would be the most common.

Comment: How about a down-pointing triangle?

Comment: Do you know of an iOS app that has an example of doing this well?

Comment: Not off the top of my head, sorry to say :-(